# How to query by node id in graphql dynamically?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, graphql-js, gridsome

I am using Vue.js with Gridsome, I have the following GraphQL query in a .vue file which is working  perfectly fine and it is returning a list of Jobs announcements.

```html
<template>
  <div class="layout">
    <header class="header">

      <nav class="nav">
        <g-link class="nav__link" to="/">Home</g-link>
        <g-link class="nav__link" to="/about/">About</g-link>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <slot/>
    <div>
        <div v-for="post in $static.eightBase.allJobs.edges">
            <strong>
                <g-link to="/">{{ post.node.title }}</g-link>
            </strong>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<static-query>
    query {
      eightBase {
        allJobs {
          edges {
            node {
                id
                company
                title
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

</static-query>
```

But here is the thing, I want to query an object by **node id** in order to get the job by details, I tried in Graphiql and the back-end configuration in Django should be fine, but I don't have any idea how it should be implemented in an app, plus I have an amateur experience on Front-end frameworks. Basically; here is how the query should work according to back-end:

```
{
  job (id: "Sm9iTm9kZTo4") {
    description
    company
    category
    description
    id
  }
}
```

What are your suggestions?

Comment: https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables